The user is not presented on the List after click on add user button
I'm trying to redo UIKit codes in SwiftUI. I implemented a list of users with an add users button. But I have a bug that when I click on the add users button, nothing happens, the user is not shown in the List.
import SwiftUI

struct User {
    let id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct UserListView: View {
    @State private var users: [User] = []
    @State private var selectedUser: User?

    var body: some View {
        List(users, id: \.id) { user in
            Text(user.name)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedUser = user
                }
        }
    }

    func addUser(_ user: User) {
        users.append(user)
    }
}

struct UserDetailView: View {
    @Binding var user: User?

    var body: some View {
        if let user = user {
            Text("User Details: \(user.name)")
        } else {
            Text("No user selected")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedUser: User?
    @State private var userList = UserListView()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            userList
            UserDetailView(user: $selectedUser)
            Button("Add User") {
                let newUser = User(id: Int.random(in: 1...1000), name: "New User")
                userList.addUser(newUser)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
{

The code is running but I have this bug. Any tip?

I tested both solutions (@JoakimDanielson and HerlandroHermogenes) and both worked. I thank you a lot friends. I do not know what answer I mark as the right one. Because both are the good one.

In addition to fixing the code, it is possible to improve it:
Remove direct coupling: UserListView directly manages the state of users, which makes it difficult to share this state with other views.
Fix communication between views: The update of selectedUser is not propagated efficiently between views.
Bonus: While we're at it, let's use a little SOLID: Violation of the single responsibility principle: UserListView is managing both the display and the data logic.
With the Mediator Design Pattern we can solve this:
Implement another view UserMediator that acts as an intermediary between the views and the data.
import SwiftUI

struct User: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var name: String
}

// Mediator (ViewModel)

class UserMediator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users: [User] = []
    @Published var selectedUser: User?

    func addUser(_ user: User) {
        users.append(user)
    }

    func selectUser(_ user: User) {
        selectedUser = user
    }
}

struct UserListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var mediator: UserMediator

    var body: some View {
        List(mediator.users) { user in
            Text(user.name)
                .onTapGesture {
                    mediator.selectUser(user)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct UserDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var mediator: UserMediator

    var body: some View {
        if let user = mediator.selectedUser {
            Text("User Details: \(user.name)")
        } else {
            Text("No user selected")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var mediator = UserMediator()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            UserListView(mediator: mediator)
            UserDetailView(mediator: mediator)
            Button("Add User") {
                let newUser = User(id: Int.random(in: 1...1000), name: "New User")
                mediator.addUser(newUser)
            }
        }
    }
}

The Mediator manages the state of users and the selection of the current user. The views (UserListView and UserDetailView) now observe the UserMediator and react to its changes.

@State var selectedUser: User? is better. @StateObject is for asynchronous loading/saving like using delegates or Combine.

Ya! Great tip. I am still learning! I already updated.

You should define the array of users at the top level (ContentView) and then pass it to the other view.
Then you should not have a view as a State property like that, add it directly to the view body instead.
To make selection work you need amongst other thing pass the selection property to your list view.
All in all the ContentView should look something like this
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedUser: User?
    @State private var userList = [User]()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            UserListView(users: $userList, selectedUser: $selectedUser)
            UserDetailView(user: selectedUser)
            Button("Add User") {
                let newUser = User(id: Int.random(in: 1...1000), name: "New User")
                userList.append(newUser)
            }
        }
    }
}

and in UserListView change the property declarations to
@Binding var users: [User]
@Binding var selectedUser: User?

For the detail view the user can be let declared since it doesn't change
let user: User? 

